# Salesforce OAuth 2.0 API: get refresh_token with authorization URL launched in a normal browser

Tags: salesforce, oauth-2.0

In this page, it is mentioned `refresh_token` is returned only for callback URLs that do not start with HTTPS or point back to salesforce.

> https://na5.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/remoteaccess_oauth_user_agent_flow.htm

However, in the SF->setup->develop->remote application creation page it takes only URL starting with HTTPS or an arbitrary string like abcd'.

Are there any tricks to get the refresh_token when the authorization URL ( i.e., OAuth authorization) is launched in a browser?

We want to use refresh_token to revalidate access_token ( when it expires) without having to prompt the login window.

Comment: Nevermind, we were using the wrong flow( user-agent flow). If we use WebServer flow we get refresh_token sent to https: urls as well.

Comment: Just to note, you can specify HTTP is the domain is `localhost` when registering your application.

Comment: @so_mv - consider moving your comment to an answer, then marking it correct, so folks can find it more easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We were using the wrong flow( user-agent flow). If we use `WebServer flow` we get refresh_token sent to `https: urls` as well.