# OAuth REST access_token and instance_url expiry time?

Tags: rest, oauth, salesforce, oauth-2.0, restful-authentication

I am working with Oauth2.0. In that i could able get the access_token and instance_url. Is there any expiry time for these two.

Can I store them and use it for all my REST calls without getting the new access_token and the instance_url. Is it possible for me to use it for long hours or even days.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The access token is only valid for the length of a session (as defined in the Salesforce Org's settings — I believe the longest this can be is 8 hours without activity), as it's actually a session ID, that said, you should also be given a refresh token. The refresh token has a much longer lifetime and can be used to authenticate the user once the session has expired, without them having to enter any credentials — this allows you to do it in the background without them even having to concern themselves with the login process.

[model metrics do a good job of explaining the token flow here](http://www.modelmetrics.com/tomgersic/oauth-2-0-for-salesforce-com/).

Comment: Actually, refresh_tokens aren't handed out unless you're building a mobile app or In-SalesForce app.  See http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com and search for "Note that refresh_token is only sent if either of the following is the case".  I found this out after 4 hours of trying to figure out why the ****ing thing wasn't giving me one.  :)  I'm happy to be proven wrong, though..   EDIT: I stand corrected.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997747/salesforce-oauth-2-0-api-get-refresh-token-with-authorization-url-launched-in-a.